# How can I cast a parameter to "Array[(some other)_0(in value $anonfun)]" in Scala?

Tags: scala, wildcard, type-parameter

I have some code like this:

```
case class FunctionCommand[A](function: Function1[Array[A], Unit])

class MyClass(commands: List[FunctionCommand[_]]) {
  def foo(parametersForEachFunction: Seq[Array[_]]) {
    assert(commands.size == parametersForEachFunction.size)
    for ((command, parameter) <- commands zip parametersForEachFunction) {
      command.function(parameter)
    }
  }
}
```

And it does not compile:

```
MyClass.scala:7: type mismatch;
found   : Array[(some other)_0(in value $anonfun)] where type (some other)_0(in value $anonfun)
required: Array[_0(in value $anonfun)] where type _0(in value $anonfun)
       command.function(parameter)
                        ^
```

I wonder what `Array[(some other)_0(in value $anonfun)]` is. Can I write something like `command.function(parameter.asInstanceOf[????])` to let it compiles?

I have a workaround. I replace `command.function(parameter)` to:

```
def forceInvoke[A](command: FunctionCommand[A], parameter: Any) {
  command.function(parameter.asInstanceOf[A])
}
forceInvoke(command, parameter)
```

And it compiles.

But I still want to know if there is a way to cast the `parameter` to correct type at runtime inlinely.

Comment: Use your workaround. Your goal is such that the Scala type system will get in the way of the flexibility you want.

Comment: You cannot lose type and then want it back. If you want types, don't use `_` anywhere, period. If you want a list of different known types, then you want an `HList`. See [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) in that case.

Comment: I am an engineer, not a mathematician. And there is no `λ`, `ℤ`, `⊤`  etc on my keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to write it like this:

```
for ((command: FunctionCommand[_], parameter) <- commands zip parametersForEachFunction) {
  command.function(parameter)
}
```

Comment: This way is OK for Scala 2.9.1, but cause warning for Scala 2.10-M2:
`MyClass.scala:6: recovering from existential Skolem type error in tree 
temp3.function()
with type Array[_$1] => Unit
 expected type = Array[_$1] => Unit
 context = <synthetic> var temp5: Array[_$1] => Unit = temp3.function()
      for ((command: FunctionCommand[_], parameter) <- commands zip parametersForEachFunction) {
`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your `FunctionCommand#function` requires a correctly-parameterized array, while you can't prove that the parameter in `parametersForEachFucntion` is of the correct type. You can't do this at runtime either due to type erasure.

The following works, abandoning the parameterization (although this is effectively just what you had before in your other question):

```
case class FunctionCommand(function: Function1[Array[_], Unit])

class MyClass(commands: List[FunctionCommand]) {
  def foo(parametersForEachFunction: Seq[Array[_]]) {
    assert(commands.size == parametersForEachFunction.size)
    for ((command, parameter) <- commands zip parametersForEachFunction) {
      command.function(parameter)
    }
  }
}

val fc = FunctionCommand(xs => xs foreach println)
val mc = new MyClass(List(fc))

scala> mc.foo(List(Array(1,2,3)))
1
2
3
```

Comment: The solution is not acceptable for me, because I need a `List` of elements with different type parameter, but `val mc = new MyClass(List(FunctionCommand { (_: Array[String]) foreach println }, FunctionCommand { (_: Array[Int]) foreach println}))` does not compile.